# MacMini (running Ubuntu 14.04) loses wlan connection when uploading larger files (several 100 mb) via ownCloud

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, owncloud-server

I installed **Ubuntu 14.04** on an old MacMini with the intention of running it as a homeserver.
Additionally I installed ownCloud and tried to sync some files both from a laptop running elementaryOS and a desktop running windows 7.

Syncing smaller files workes like a charm (4000 files at <10mb each) but when it comes to bigger files (1 GB ubuntu iso e.g.) the upload failes after 20-100mb. I can't ping the server anymore and the server can't ping me. **It still shows up in our router as connected though.**

Disconnecting and reconnecting the wlan connection fixes the issue until the next attempt at syncing.

Edit: I also had to install the wlan driver with this manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2#Wireless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
The driver was the problem. I tried using an external wireless adapter and everything works fine.
Seems like the manually installed driver crashed under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used ownCloud; so what I am about to say may not be relevant. However, I have run into situations with Dropbox and other cloud services where I needed to keep chunk sizes to set amounts (20-40 MB) for large files. My second thought is that ownCloud (if memory serves correct, is PHP driven so you may need to modify your server's PHP settings to increase the max upload size.

**edit**
Did a quick Google search and found this which may be relevant to you http://doc.owncloud.org/server/6.0/admin_manual/configuration/configuring_big_file_upload.html